# What's the name of this figure of speech playing with the use-mention distinction?

Tags: single-word-requests, figures-of-speech

The following is a figure of speech I've seen a couple of times in my native language of German.
Though I have no reason to doubt it exists, I don't remember ever seeing it used in English, so I've come up with two examples myself:

> - Every time you wear your heart on your sleeve, or give someone short shrift, you're using a phrase coined by Shakespeare.
> - People who take everything for "granite" might not be the most educated.

These sentences deal with the ***mentioning*** of these terms - *saying* "I'm wearing my heart on my sleeve", or misspelling "granted" as "granite" - but they're worded like they deal with their ***using***, as if they were about actually wearing your heart on your sleeve or taking things for granted.

To once again illustrate the difference, here are the same sentence with the figure of speech removed:

> - Every time you say "I'm wearing my heart on a sleeve", or use the phrase "to give someone short shrift", you're using a phrase coined by Shakespeare.
> - People who say "take for granite" instead of "take for granted" might not be the most educated.

No list I've used has mentioned this figure of speech. I could just name it "**equating usage and mentioning**" and call it a day (and by calling it a day, using a phrase originating in the 19th century, just by the way),
but I'd really like to know ***if this has been observed before, and given an official name***.

Comment: They're generally called "play on words", I don't know if there's a more specific term for this particular type.

Comment: Philosophers just call them "use/mention equivalences" or "use/mention confusions".

Comment: Isn't the phrase "to give someone short shrift"/ (No ***a*** or ***the***).  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=given+a+short+shrift%2Cgiven+short+shrift&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiven%20a%20short%20shrift%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgiven%20short%20shrift%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Jim seems to be the case; edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're ***[puns](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pun)*** that depend on the use-mention distinction, as many puns do, so we could reasonably call them "use-mention puns", a phrase that's [had some use, but not a lot](https://www.google.com/search?q="use-mention+pun").

Comment: The second one is definitely a pun on granite/granted. The first seems not to be in the same category at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach suggesting that Shakespeare is involved in what you are actually doing is punning. It's not a slap-your-thighs, split-your-sides, wet-your-pants hilarious pun, but it's a pun.

Comment: I have to agree with Andrew Leach. And the use-mention distinction appears to come from philosophy. I assumed the question was about English usage...

Comment: @daniel are you trolling?

Comment: Because I disagree with you and agree with AL I am being disruptive? Wow.

Comment: @daniel no, because your arguing against using a phrase from the philosophy of language in answering a question about usage of terms in discussing language by saying "I assumed the question was about English usage". Is that trying to be clever or something?

Comment: If a standard answer is available, why resort to the philosophy of language? Instead of attacking me or my intentions why not focus on the merits of the question. I think your answer is potentially confusing. I did in fact assume the question was about English and was genuinely confused to see a philosophy-related response.

Comment: @daniel you're coming here and telling me I'm only allowed to use English words and phrases that came into English from certain fields (even though the question is about figures of speech, and the use I am making is from philosophers studying language). Now you're saying "a standard answer is available". If it's available, why don't you post it instead of the irrelevant thing you did post?

Comment: As usual @JonHanna is spot on, Shakespeare, being the first to coin those two phrases in writing! The **pun** is that wearing your heart on your sleeve or giving someone the short shrift is not the same as using the phrase: use-mention distinction!

Comment: @ScotM it would be cool if someone could think of something more specific again, though.

Comment: Accepting this answer because the search results given capture the essence of my question well enough, and it suggests that there's probably no official name besides that.

Answer (score 1):

To me, there is a double meaning that occurs because the sentence is first parsed literally, and then parsed figuratively. This kind of word play may be considered a type of ***paraprosdokian***:

> A **paraprosdokian** is a figure of speech in which the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian)</sub>

I do agree that the second sentence may qualify as a **pun** on *granite*/*granted*.

Comment: While I still maintain that the first is also a form of pun, I think you have the better answer here; though you don't address the use-mention aspect of it, "a use-mention paraprosdokian" seems reasonable, and I think you're on the button by thinking of paraprosdokians rather than puns.

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a paraprosdokian, since to me that implies that the "punchline" must be at the end and changing its position would diminish the quality of the sentence as a paraprosdokian. The examples I gave, however, would work just as well in reverse: *"You're using phrases coined by Shakespeare every time you..."*

Comment: @vvye: I assumed that the "figure of speech" of failing to distinguish *use* from *mention* was intended for humor, since otherwise it is just an ambiguous statement or a logical error.